# How to create a singleton actor in Java using the AKKA framework?

Tags: session, singleton, akka, actor

I have an actorSystem with a Supervisor and a few children. How to have a singleton actor in the actor system? Does making the constructor private suffice this?

There are multiple actors writing to the database, this causes a deadlock , in order to avoid this, I want the actor to be singleton.

Comment: As I remember Akka actor are created using Props, if you want yo add restriction to create only one instance, you may create own props which then would hold ActorRef. But it looks like a crutch. Just create one actor and that ia it :)

Comment: From what I understand, actors run parallely with the default empty mail box strategy. How to avoid this and block the thread when the actor is processing a job

Comment: sounds like an evil hack :) There is a point that you should not think about threads synchronization with actor model. Could you describe your problem a little bit more (in question section). Maybe there is a good Akka pattern for it.

Comment: Just updated the question